# Logstash Jdbc_streaming filter plugin returns an empty set using "parameters" option

Tags: jdbc, logstash

I'm using the jdbc input plugin to get data from "table1":

```
statement => "SELECT * FROM table1 where id=1"
Result is : id:1 and id_subscriber:1
```

Then I'm using the ***jdbc_streaming*** filter plugin to get more data from "table2" using the "**id_subscriber**" field value from the previous statement, so I'm using the following statement which gets me an empty result :

```
statement => "SELECT * FROM table2 where id_subscriber = :idsub"
parameters => { "idsub" => "%{id_subscriber}"}
target => "arrayOfResults" #arrayOfResults is an empty array
```

If I use the id_subscribe value directly in the following statement, I get the four records I'm looking for :

```
statement => "SELECT * FROM table2 where id_subscriber = 1"
target => "arrayOfResults" # I get the right result
```

Can you tell me what Im I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I did not understand how the "parameters" option works.
The right answer if someone came across this issue is simply :

```
`parameters => { "idsub" => "id_subscriber"}`
```

The right sided part of **parameters** was referring to the field name and not it's value.